# Rename files based on csv file values - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, rename

I have a CSV file with a column called "id" and I have a directory with files.I would like to rename those files according to the values that are in the cells below the "id" column.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

import os

path = os.chdir('/Users/Utilizador/pythonProjects/files')

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Utilizador/pythonProjects/todos-cantar-palavras.csv', encoding='utf8')

i = 0

for file in os.listdir(path):
    new_file_name = df['id']
    os.rename(file, new_file_name)
   
    i = i + 1
```

It returns the following error:

TypeError: rename: dst should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not Series

I imagine it should be quite easy, but because I am giving the first steps all the help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of df['id'] you need to write df['id'].iloc[i] because df['id'] will give you series of value i.e whole column instead of single value that why you are getting error

```
import pandas as pd

import os

path = os.chdir('/Users/Utilizador/pythonProjects/files')

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Utilizador/pythonProjects/todos-cantar-palavras.csv', encoding='utf8')

i = 0

for file in os.listdir(path):
    new_file_name = df['id'].iloc[i]
    os.rename(path+'/'+file, path+'/'+new_file_name)
   
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you @Kapil Musale. Also I added the file extension with `new_file_name = df['id'].iloc[i]+'.pdf` Best regards